# edit multiple database rows in a symfony form

Tags: symfony1

symfony created a dogform class which can edit one dog entry in the database.
to display the form in the view i use currently:

```
<?php echo $form; ?>
```

well now i want to edit multiple dogs at once (in one page).
how do i do this?
i think i need the same form multiple times but with different initial data (dogs)

Answer (score 1):

You need one form, because you can only submit one form at a time, according to html spec.
This form will embed a collection of DogForm.

```
class DogCollectionForm extends sfForm
{
  $dogs = Doctrine::getTable('Dog')->findAll();
  foreach ($dogs as $i => $dog)
  {
    $dogForm = new DogForm($dog);
    $this->embedForm($i, $dogForm);
  }
}
```

As an enhancement, pass $dogs to form from action as a parameter.

Comment: ok thank you, display of all rows (in the database) is working, but now i have a problem to save it.

Comment: (because sfForm has no own save method). I tried to get the embedded forms (with $this->form->getEmbeddedForms()) in my update action and save each one separately...but i get an error (_csrf_token [Required.])

Comment: No, sfForm has a save method, and it saves all embedded forms by default. You must be doing something wrong. Have a look at this example: http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms